# Solution/project file for Java IDE

Tags: eclipse, visual-studio-2010, netbeans

Is there a way to make a double-clickable solution/project file using a Java IDE such as Eclipse or Netbeans, in the same way as the `.sln` files of Visual Studio?

So that when I move my source code between computers, all I have to do is double-click on the solution/project file and the project will be automatically loaded?

Answer (score 0):

Open eclipse, in Menu file->Import, you can find some useful menu-item to open a java project.
In fact, Some times NO project file you want.